# Which food items heal you?

Tags: pitman

In [Pitman](http://www.desura.com/games/pitman)'s help topic for 'items', it mentions that some food items won't just fill his belly, they will also heal him, but it doesn't say which ones.  I'd like to prioritize picking up healing food items over standard ones due to my limited inventory capacity.

Which food items heal you, and by how much?

[image: Some food items will heal Pitman as well as satisfy his hunger]